# Use of variable in LIKE condition of PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where I need to search all records like '00456159/%'.
In database there are two records 00456159/A and 00456159/I. But in the below code that I'm using it does not give any of the records.Can someone point out the mistake that I'm doing? Thanks,

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE

Cursor c2(v_comp IN VARCHAR2) is select  distinct rate_agreement_nbr rag FROM APL_PRICING.rate_agreement 
WHERE  RATE_AGREEMENT_NBR like   ''''||v_comp||'%'||'''';

v_comp1 VARCHAR2(15);

BEGIN

v_comp1 :=SUBSTR('00456159/A',1,9);

For v_rec in c2(v_comP1)
loop
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rec.rag);
end loop;

END;
```

Answer (score 6):

Your predicate is concatenating `''''` which adds an extra literal quote character (`'`) to the start and end of your expression. The data you're matching, however, does not have any embedded quotes, so the query does not find any matching rows.

Instead of

```
''''||v_comp||'%'||'''';
```

use this:

```
v_comp||'%';
```